# how can I redirect to a dynamic url using HTML?

Tags: python, html, css, django, authentication

My code is

```
{% if user.employee.employee_id == 2 %}
            <head> 
            <title>HTML Redirect</title> 
            <meta http-equiv="refresh"
                content="1; url = employee/2/" /> 
        </head> 
{% elif user.employee.employee_id == 4 %}
        <head> Wait!
        <title>HTML Redirect</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="refresh"
            content="1; url = employee/4/" /> 
    </head>
```

As you can see from above, i am using if elif to access pages based on the id of employee and this method is not efficient. I want to change the employee_id to variable. something like this:

```
x = user.employee.empolyee_id
                <head> Wait!
            <title>HTML Redirect</title> 
            <meta http-equiv="refresh"
                content="1; url = employee/x/" /> 
            </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

put the `employee_id` in url:

```
url = employee/{{user.employee.employee_id}}/
```